# Krippendorff's Alpha for non-adjacent pairs of subjects

Tags: r

I should like to calculate Krippendorff’s Alpha coefficient of raters reliability for a study with many raters/coders and identical subjects (ordinal data) using R package `irr`.

Using the example “C data from Krippendorff” in the package irr, how can I calculate the Alpha coefficient voor non-adjacent pairs of raters (i.e rater 1 and rater 4)?

How should I further automate this calculation process by `for…loop` scripting for all pairs of objects (both adjacent and non-adjacent)?

Here is the script from `irr`:

```
# the "C" data from Krippendorff
nmm<-matrix(c(1,1,NA,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,
1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,NA,5,5,5,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,3,NA),nrow=4)
kripp.alpha(nmm,"ordinal")
#rater per row; rated subject per column; NAs allowed
#better scripted this would become:
kripp.alpha(nmm [1:4, 1:12],"ordinal")
# adjacent pairs can be calculated easily:
kripp.alpha(nmm [2:4, 1:12],"ordinal")
# I should like to calculate KrippAlpha for non-adjacent pair 1 versus 4
```

Comment: See `combn` and `apply` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer in Related items column

## I should like to calculate KrippAlpha for non-adjacent pair 1 versus 4

script below works fine:

```
   kripp.alpha(nmm [c(1,4), 1:12],"ordinal")
```